# Correction of data reduces quality of results

Tags: logistic, confidence-interval, standard-error

I'm running a logistic regression with a small sample size: I corrected my data for outliers after checking the standard error (1.07) and the confidence intervall (0.51 - 11.55) for one of my variables. Those with a cook distance > 1 and DFBeta > 1 were excluded which resulted in an even higher standard error (2.15) and confidence intervall (0.15 - 676.20). I assume this happened due to the small sample size. Is it right to include those again that were excluded before, though they influence the regression so much? How would my argumentation for that step look like?

Comment: It sounds like you're "correcting" your independent variable. If so, *why*?

Comment: @ Glen_b The main reason I do this is because I read that I have to check those values (Cook index and so on) and if those values are too high it is recommended to exclude them. I really don't have much clue about statistics so I just follow the instructions in my book.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not right to include those again, and it doesn't have anything to do with sample size.

Often, it is easy to fit bad data well. But then you are taking advantage of particular qualities of your data that will (probably) not work in the population you are inferring to (and if you aren't inferring, why do inferential statistics?)

You do not want to include points that influence the model unduly. See [Anscombe's Quartet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anscombe%27s_quartet) for examples with correlation; the point is the same with regression (including logistic regression).

It seems like there are problems with your model, but it's impossible to say what they are without a lot more info. It might just be that your theory is wrong.